# Class X has no attribute Y (Python)

Tags: oop, inheritance, python-2.7

I am new to Python OOP and I am trying to have some exercise with the Inheritance.

```
class userProfile():
    def __init__(self):
        self.listPost = []
```

On the different file...

```
from Profile import userProfile

class userPosting(userProfile):
    def __init__(self):
        self.compactList = []
        self.listPost = [] #Complete Post consisting Post, Comment, and userTag
        self.newPost = ""
        self.Index_P = 0
        self.userIndex_P = 0 #Set once user CLICKS
        self.searchPost = ""

    def writePost(self):
        self.newPost = raw_input("Post: ")
        self.listPost = [self.newPost,....] #The content of newpost will be appended to listPost with other variables
        self.compactList.append(self.listPost) #Now, compactList is a list that contains listPost as a whole
        userProfile.listPost.append(self.compactList) # sending Post to the Profile
```

Now, when I try to create the objects in a new file named 'TestDrive' after importing all necessary files:

```
SNS_Profile = userProfile()
SNS_Posting = userPosting()

SNS_Profile.__init__()
SNS_Posting.__init__() #I am not sure if I have to write this explicitly. Won't Python initialize the variables itself?

SNS_Posting.writePost()
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: class userProfile has no attribute listPost
```

Comment: You do not have to call `__init__` here

Comment: Gee, thanks! but then, when will the variables be initialized? (I am so sorry for such stupid question)

Comment: The __init__ method is called automatically when you create new instances. Like this: userProfile().

Comment: In Python, class names are conventionally titlecase. Like this: UserProfile, UserPosting.

Comment: Apologies for being so vague. I expected when the user gives an input that will be stored to self.listPost, it will be appended to self.compactList. After that, the content of the self.compactList shall be forwarded to listPost of userProfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `userPost` extends `userProfile`, you can just reference the `listPost` variable directly, using `self.listPost`.

```
self.listPost.append(self.compactList)
```

However, it is not entirely clear what it is you intend to do. There seems to be some redundancy here:

```
self.listPost = [self.newPost,....] 
self.compactList.append(self.listPost)
userProfile.listPost.append(self.compactList)
```

What is your expected result for these three lines?

I think that what you are failing to understand is the concept of inheritance. By extending userProfile, userPost **is** a userProfile.

Here is another example of this concept:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def eat(self):
        print 'Animal[', self.name, '].eat()'

class Dog(Animal):
    def eat(self):
        print 'Dog[', self.name,'].eat()'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Animal('Sparky')
    a.eat() # -- Animal[ Sparky ].eat()
    d = Dog('Sonic')
    d.eat() # -- Dog[ Sonic ].eat()
```

What I'm attempting to demonstrate is that because `Dog` extends `Animal`, it **is** an `Animal`. The property `name` is **inherited**. Notice that I don't reference `Animal` anywhere in the body of the `Dog` class.

**UPDATE**

I suggest that you re-evaluate what it is that you are trying to do and why inheritance is your solution. If you have trouble clearly identifying why, you should look at some other examples of OOP with Python. Chapter 4 of the [Python Practice Book](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/) should be very insightful for you.

Comment: I have addded comment to my post to clarify. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example! Now I clearly understood where I was wrong. But could you suggest me how I should able to transfer the data of "listPost" of Posting to the "listPost" to the Profile?

Answer (score 1):

In writePost, look at the line

```
userProfile.listPost.append(self.compactList)
```

`userPosting` is a child class of `userProfile`, and will thus get access to all variables of `userPosting`, but this does not work the other way around - `userProfile` does not have access to the variables belonging to any of its children. (how could `userProfile` know which other classes that have subclassed it?).

You should probably look into a tutorial of classes though - you code in its current shape does not make any sense at all.

When you build you class hierarchy, you need to consider how you can use inheritance of classes to simplify your code. In this case, `userProfile` and `userPosting` does not have anything in common. A better way to achieve what you try to do, is to create a list `postings` in your `userProfile` class, and append new `userPostings` to this list.

**Examples of object representations that could be represented by inherited classes:**

> Math, History, Geography could inherit from a base class called Subject
>
> Chair, Table from Furniture

**And examples of objects that shouldn't be related:**

> Person and Arm -- very few things in common
>
> House, Roof -- etc.

Comment: Oh, I see. What I wanted to happen was whenever `writePost()` is used, the content of `compactList` of userPosting will be appended to `listPost` of userProfile. Any advice?

Comment: Downvoted because your explanation of visibility is wrong/irrelevant here. Removed it because your suggestion for the fix is valid.

Comment: @Eric It's correct and relevant. The error given is a result of him trying to access a variable of a child class from a parent class.

Comment: No, there are two problems here, and neither of them are those: **1.** the OP is accessing a class attribute when he means an instance attribute`, and **2.** there seems to be the assumption that a single instance can have two distinct attributes with the same name given by different classes in the heirarchy (which is not the case - instance attributes have no "owning class" context, and are distinguished solely by name.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `super(userPosting, self).__init__()` within `userPosting.__init__`

Comment: Sorry for being dumb but what is `super(...)`? Why is it necessary?